# Spring Aspectj maven - NoClassDefError for InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor

Tags: spring, maven, aop

I am using Spring AOP using maven build and getting the following error when starting the application server -

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor
```

The following is the test aspect -

```
@Aspect 
@Component
public class TestAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.controller.MyController.submitOptions(..))")
    public void logBefore(){} 

    @Before("logBefore()")
    public void printBefore() { 
        System.out.println("print before aspect is invoked.");
    }

    public TestAspect() { 

    }
}
```

The Spring configuration looks like this -

```
:
:
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">
```

:
:
:
:

```
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.test,com.example.controller"/>
     <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
     <bean id="TestAspect" class="com.example.test.TestAspect"/>
```

The pom xml has dependency on aspectjrt, aspectjweaver, aspectjtools and others... 
The aspectj-maven-plugin version of 1.5 is used.

The following is the dependencies in the pom file -

```
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
    <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Please let me know if there is any problem with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${yourSpringVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, I do have the spring related dependencies listed in the pom file. Still i am facing the same issue as listed in the original post.